# vector subspaces : exam

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given:
$$S=\left[\{(1,2,3,1),(0,-1,2,1)\}\right]<\mathbb R^4,\;T\left[\{(2,5,4,1),(3,8,5,1)\}\right]<\mathbb R^4$$

a) Are they the same subspace?

b) If $(1, 3, 1, 0)$ belongs to one of them, give the coordinates.

Any help on how to proceed?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that $(2,5,4,1)=2(1,2,3,1)-(0,-1,2,1)$ and $(3,8,5,1)=3(1,2,3,1)-2(0,-1,2,1)$ and $(1,3,1,0)=(1,2,3,1)-(0,-1,2,1)$

Comment: But what is the general procedure that you use in order to find them?

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: In general:  $$$$When checking whether two (sub)spaces coincide, you have to compare the linear span of the basis of each one.
 $$\left[\{B_1\}\right]\leq\left[\{B_2\}\right]\;\land\;\left[\{B_2\}\right]\leq\left[\{B_1\}\right]$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Any linear combination $a(1,2,3,1)+b(0,-1,2,1)$ will have the first component $a$ and the second component $2a-b$.

Comment: I could solve it, thanks!